# Exim system filter with split configuration

Tags: debian, ubuntu, exim

I would like to enable system-wide filtering so I can define some custom spam filtering. I am using the Ubuntu/Debian split configuration for Exim but cannot see where to define the system filter.

In a normal configuration, I would just the following to the main configuration:

```
system_filter = /etc/mail/exim.filter
system_filter_user = Debian-exim
system_filter_group = Debian-exim
system_filter_file_transport = address_file
system_filter_pipe_transport = address_pipe
```

However, I am unsure as to where to add these in the split configuration setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called `30_exim4-config_system_filter` in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main` which contains the following:

```
# System wide filter:
#  http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-systemwide_message_filtering.html
system_filter = /etc/mail/exim.filter
system_filter_user = Debian-exim
system_filter_group = Debian-exim
system_filter_file_transport = address_file
system_filter_pipe_transport = address_pipe
# System wide filter end.
```

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo exim -bF /etc/mail/exim.filter < /etc/mail/spam-test
sudo update-exim4.conf
sudo service exim4 restart
```

Your new filter should be working...

Comment: Where does `/etc/mail/spam-test` come from?